# How can I make a MatToolbarRow take up full width within a MatToolbar Component

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have an Angular Material MatToolbar Component and within it I have two MatToolbarRow Components.  One for a header title I would like to go across the full width of the screen.  The second has navigation buttons for the application.

But it seems a MatToolbarRow does not take up the full width within a MatToolbar component.

Here is  how it renders right now.

[image]

The following is the structure of the HTML.

Root Component [AppComponent] html:

```
<app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I put some padding on the content container in app.component.css

```
.container {
   padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
}
```

Here is my NavMenuComponent sitting at the top of AppComponent (nav-menu.component.html):

```
<header>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <mat-toolbar-row class="matToolbar-header-title">
            <app-header></app-header>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['/']">
                <mat-icon>
                   home
                </mat-icon>
            </a>
            <a mat-flat-button [routerLink]="['/vehicles']">
                Vehicles
            </a>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

I put a class called matToolbar-header-title on the top MatToolbarRow so I could try to finagle it.
So in nav-menu.component.scss for the NavMenuComponent if I put:

```
.matToolbar-header-title {
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

at least I can get it to sit all the way to the left and it renders like this:

[image]

If I inspect the MatToolbarRow(s) in the web dev tools I can see the MatToolbarRow only takes up as much space as the content needs (for both rows).

[image]

It appears it using the flex system. Unfortunatly I don't know flex yet.
I would also like the height to take up all the space of the parent (MatToolbar).

I need the title to render something like this:

[image]

For completeness here is the header.component.html which sits in the  element in NavMenuComponent

```
<div class="header-title">
    Fred's Cars, Trucks & Jeeps
</div>
```

and header.component.css looks like this:

```
.header-title {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I got the answer from the Angular Material documentation at:
https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview#positioning-toolbar-content

This is what I did in my code.
On the top MatToolbarRow I added a class called "matToolbar-header-title" so I could target the background with CSS and set the background color to black.
Within that top MatToolbarRow I wrapped the Header component  in two SPAN elements with a class called example-spacer (I have to update my code and change example-spacer to just spacer).  Then in CSS use flex to make any element with example-spacer class grow horizontally to take up all available space.

Here is the code:

nav-menu.component.html

```
<header>
   <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <mat-toolbar-row class="matToolbar-header-title">
         <span class="example-spacer"></span>
            <app-header></app-header>
         <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
      <mat-toolbar-row>
         <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['/']">
            <mat-icon>
               home
            </mat-icon>
         </a>
         <a mat-flat-button [routerLink]="['/vehicles']">
            Vehicles
         </a>
       </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

nav-menu.component.scss

```
.matToolbar-header-title {
   background-color: black;
}

.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Now it renders like this:

[image]